# Divide text in the column into two columns (text and numbers) - Google sheet or Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, regular-language

I have a document in google sheets and the column consists of the name and version, like NLog.Config.4.3.0, NLog.Config.4.4.9 and so on.
See the image below for other examples.

I need to divide this into two columns - name and version, but I'm not familiar with regular expressions so close that I can get this info.

I can use excel and then import it to the Google doc, it doesn't matter for me how to do that.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw9Yy.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

Suppose you have your string in A1, then in B1 you can enter this:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789")))
```

and in C1 this:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))+1)
```

you may need to do some adjustments if there are cases without numbers as it will produce an error, for example you can round it with an Iferror like this:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))),A1)
```

Note: A1&"0123456789" is a 'trick' to avoid the search to return error, as the search is looking for all the numbers in the array; we just need the position of the first one, thus the MIN().

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that your raw data were in A2:A, place this in B2:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(\D+)\.(.+)"),A2:A))`

The regular expression reads "Extract any number of non-digits up to but not including a period as group one, and everything remaining into group two." (In other words, "As soon as you run into a digit after a period, start group two.")

The `IFERROR` clause means, "If this pattern can't be found, just return the original cell data."

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your content is in column `A` (Google Sheets), try this `arrayformula` in any cell other than column `A`:

`=arrayformula(iferror(split(REGEXREPLACE($A:$A,"(\.)(\d+.+$)",char(6655)&"$2"),char(6655)),))`

There are two regex groups denoted in `()`:

`(\.)` and `(\d+.+$)`.

The first group looks for a dot `.` - it's escaped using `\`. The second group looks for a number (0-9) `\d`, one or more occurrences `+` then ending with `$` one or more `+` of any character `.`.

The replacement is `char(6655)` (wouldn't usually be found in your dataset), and the contents of group two `$2`.

Then the `split` function divides the text into two columns by the `char(6655)` character.

`iferror` returns nothing if nothing is split.

The `arrayformula` works down the sheet.